# simple registration form php-sql-flash connectivity?

Tags: php, mysql, flash, web-applications

I want to create simple registration form in Flash and using php-mysql can anyone give me any source of tutorial for Flash-PHP Mysql Connectivity or any example ?

and if i use Flash instead of Simple HTML so Packet sniffing software still able to capture the data ? Software like Wireshark

I want to use flash because I want to secure Login credentials POST Method without using SSL so i'm thinking to develop registration in flash for security

please suggest me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is a client side application and therefore has to somehow communicate login credentials from the client to the server. HTML forms also exist on the client side before they are submitted, sending their credentials from the client to the server.

Both of these techniques have to use a communication protocol for the sending of login credentials. In the case of HTML forms it is either a GET or POST request. In the case of Flash, it is also very commonly a GET or POST request. Both are clear text protocols which are not encrypted except with the use of SSL.

Flash has the ability to perform XML and sometimes even raw socket requests but no matter what you will require some sort of encryption encapsulation. The most commonly accepted, easily available and probably cheapest method to do this is SSL.

**Summary:** There are very few options available to you other than SSL and Flash does very little to expand those options.